# database agnostic example using liquibase using sequences

Tags: mysql, oracle, postgresql, liquibase

In exploring the nuance of using sequences vs AUTO-INCREMENT I'm struggling to find a realistic example of how to make a database agnostic liquibase project.

**Scenario requirements:**

Create a table with some columns, insert data WHERE the value of PKID is some computed value

My starting point was an existing postgres db that referenced a .sql file in the `changeSet` to create a sequence:

```
<sqlFile path="create-tables.sql" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
```

SQL from create-tables.sql

```
CREATE TABLE new_table (
  pkid integer NOT NULL,
);

CREATE SEQUENCE new_table_pkid_seq
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
NO MINVALUE
NO MAXVALUE
CACHE 1;
```

there than was a changeSet to insert records based on the sequence, as follows:

```
<changeSet author="yoman" id="123">
    <insert tableName="new_table">
        <column name="pkid" valueComputed="nextval('new_table_pkid_seq')"/>
    </insert>
</changeSet>
```

However, MySQL doesn't support sequences.  Oracle also uses sequences in a different syntax.

So I don't know how to make a solution that will work for all three?

My thoughts were

1. Drop the use of the sequence and/or function and use AUTO-INCREMENT for all 3 db's.  Then remove the create-tables.sql and create the table using liquibase XML `changeSet` syntax.
2. Create a function in postgres instead of a sequence and create the same name function in Oracle and MySQL as well, that simulates a sequence function.  Then specify the function name:

`<column name="pkid" valueComputed="INCREMENT_FUNCTION()"/>`

Problems..

1. The problem is I don't know what the XML would look like if I tried #1 (do I use `dbms` for instance?)? Also, sequences provide more flexibility so not sure other contributors would agree with using AUTO-INCREMENT.
2. Not sure how to actually generate a common function in liquibase for those 3 target hosts.

As I understand it liquibase is a tool that drives the concept of database agnostic setups.  But I can't find any documentation on some basic examples of how to create a liquibase project that works against multiple database targets.

Answer (score 0):

Options:

1. Oracle 12c supports `AUTO_INCREMENT`, so that is one option.
2. Don't try to be database agnostic. I have seen many companies in the past try to build database agnostic applications. The problem is that you end up with compromises and and you end up with poor applications, that can run everywhere. Most of those companies are now out of business
3. There is the concept of a CODE_CONTROL table; but this is such a bad option, I am not even going to explain it!